# How to display the number of search results (custom search script)

Tags: php, search

Im try makeing search function for my site, this is the code http://pastebin.com/GN1NUE7E
But i need help to display the number of search results.

Comment: Cameron Diaz hacks in PHP? Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the result of function mysql_num_rows:

```
$rows_num = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);
```

And then print it:

```
echo $rows_num;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already calling [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), which tells you how many rows are in your result. Consider the following use in the example from the documentation:

```
<?php

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
  mysql_select_db("database", $link);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

You have the following in your code:

```
if( mysql_num_rows( $raw_results ) > 0 )
```

You're checking to see how many results were returned. All you would need to do is assign the value of `mysql_num_rows()` to a variable, or call it directly.